# Why DLL import as module works in Python2 and not in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dll

I'm trying to import a **DLL library** to interact with a PTZ Camera and i'm not familiar with this. *Despite of all my search, i was not able to found a solution.*

This code **works well** on Python 2.

```
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("PTZ.dll")
from PTZ import PTZDevice, PTZType  
self.cam = PTZDevice.GetDevice('Logitech ConferenceCam CC3000e', PTZType.Relative)
```

But if I try to run on Python 3, I get this **error**. `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PTZ'`

**Have you any hint on how I could achieve this on Python 3 ?** *I need to migrate on this version for others features.*

Comment: I deleted my answer because it's apparently been awhile since I've used ctypes. Refer to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html). It shows how the library is used.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yep i've already see the documentation but it doesn't refer the import module from DLL that i was using in Python 2, so that's why i asked here :/